# Customise home screen on Hisense Vision TV

Tags: android-tv, smart-tv

Just purchased a Hisense Vision TV which is powered by Android.

I have just installed the Plex app and want to put the icon on the home screen.

Does anyone know how to customise this screen??

Some of the things I've tried:

- Clicking the option key on the remote - just brings up three themes to choose from
- Clicking setting button on remote - bring up the normal settings menu
- Settings -> Local -> Apps - displays app info
- Drag and drop using the air remote feature - doesn't do anything
- Searching google - brings up many reviews, some videos, but no actual hits.